# Better way of using JS function

Tags: javascript, function

This code is a simple calculator. Enter 2 numbers and hit the required operation to get the output and there is nothing wrong in this code. But, I'm trying to find the possible ways of reducing the JavaScript code to the shortest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        function add(){
            var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('no1').value);
            var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('no2').value);
            document.write(a+b);
        }
        function sub(){
            var a = document.getElementById('no1').value;
            var b = document.getElementById('no2').value;
            document.write(a-b);
        }
        function mult(){
            var a = document.getElementById('no1').value;
            var b = document.getElementById('no2').value;
            document.write(a*b);
        }
        function div(){
            var a = document.getElementById('no1').value;
            var b = document.getElementById('no2').value;
            document.write(a/b);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="no1">
    <input type="text" id="no2">
    <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="add()">
    <input type="button" value="SUB" onclick="sub()"> 
    <input type="button" value="MULT" onclick="mult()">
    <input type="button" value="DIV" onclick="div()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use event delegation instead, on the body. On click, check to see if the clicked element is an input with a value - if so, look up the appropriate function to run on an object indexed by values (eg `ADD`, `SUB`).

You also might consider using `type="number"` encourage the user to only enter numeric values:

```js
const fns = {
  ADD: (a, b) => a + b,
  SUB: (a, b) => a - b,
  MULT: (a, b) => a * b,
  DIV: (a, b) => a / b,
}
const [no1, no2] = ['no1', 'no2'].map(id => document.getElementById(id));
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!e.target.matches('input[value]')) {
    return;
  }
  const { value } = e.target;
  const fn = fns[value];
  console.log(
    fn(Number(no1.value), Number(no2.value))
  );
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="no1">
<input type="number" id="no2">
<input type="button" value="ADD">
<input type="button" value="SUB">
<input type="button" value="MULT">
<input type="button" value="DIV">
```

It could be made even shorter (by not selecting the elements ahead of time, or by relying on the ids being on the window, or by not storing temporary values in variables), but it'd be less efficient and/or less readable, so I wouldn't recommend it:

```js
const fns = {
  ADD: (a, b) => a + b,
  SUB: (a, b) => a - b,
  MULT: (a, b) => a * b,
  DIV: (a, b) => a / b,
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('input[value]')) {
    console.log(fns[target.value](Number(no1.value), Number(no2.value)));
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="no1">
<input type="number" id="no2">
<input type="button" value="ADD">
<input type="button" value="SUB">
<input type="button" value="MULT">
<input type="button" value="DIV">
```

Comment: Good answer! This is really well coded. I'm on mobile and haven't found a good way to test code, but if the number inputs are empty, I think it might return NaN? It might need a validation and default

Comment: The empty string, when cast to a number, becomes 0, so it's OK.

Comment: okay! Nicely done. I love seeing code structured to be dynamic. I'm going to see if I can rival it with a constructor or class using templating a bit later. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do.

```js
const inputX = document.querySelector("#x");
const inputY = document.querySelector("#y");
const output = document.querySelector("#z");
const select = document.querySelector("#op");

const operations = {
    add: (x, y) => x + y,
    sub: (x, y) => x - y,
    mul: (x, y) => x * y,
    div: (x, y) => x / y,
};

const render = (x, y, op) => {
    inputX.value = x;
    inputY.value = y;
    output.value = op(x, y);
    select.value = op.name;

    inputX.onchange = () => render(parseFloat(inputX.value, 10), y, op);
    inputY.onchange = () => render(x, parseFloat(inputY.value, 10), op);
    select.onchange = () => render(x, y, operations[select.value]);
};

render(0, 0, operations.add);
```

```html
<input id="x" type="number"/>
<select id="op">
  <option value="add">+</option>
  <option value="sub">-</option>
  <option value="mul">*</option>
  <option value="div">/</option>
</select>
<input id="y" type="number"/> =
<output id="z"></output>
```

It's not as terse as CertainPerformance's answer. However, I feel that it's more understandable. In addition, it's reactive. Finally, although I haven't made use of event delegation here you can certainly use event delegation instead.